# How I can copy finction with passed arguments, as a function, not a result?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
def test(a, b):
    value = random.randint(0, a + b)
    return value

value = test(1, 20)
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(f"It's a result function {test(1, 20)}")
    print(f"It's a result variable {value}") # I want, that value will be different in each loop
```

I want, that value will be different in each

Comment: Move `value = test(1, 20)` inside the for-loop to have a different `value` each iteration.

Comment: I know, but I need exactly hand over value, as one argument in function with already passed argemtns inside function.

Comment: You cannot call a function once, and expect multiple different `value`s as a result. Each function call produces a single return value. So if you want multiple different `value`s, you'll have to call `test` multiple times. You could store the arguments in variables if you want to call `test` multiple times with the same arguments. Place `a = 1` and `b = 20` before the for-loop, then `value = test(a, b)` inside the for-loop. This doesn't really make sense for the hardcoded parameters, but might be useful when they are a result of some other function. eg. `a = get_value_a()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


def rand_sum(a, b):
    return random.randint(0, a + b)


value = rand_sum(1, 20)
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(f"It's a result function {rand_sum(1, 20)}")
    print(f"It's a result variable {value}")
```

In fact, the last two rows returns different values as they call the "rand_sum" function two times.

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: The "test" is a special function in python, and you should set another Func_name like me.

Comment: "test" is a module , only if you import it explicitly